# Code compiles with VS but not with MinGW

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

I am using a library created not by me. The code compiles with VS2015 and runs as is should using VS2015. I want to compile this with a MinGW GCC compiler to eventually make it run on a larger computer which runs on Linux and uses GCC compiler. The library should work with VS, MinGW for Windows and GCC for Linux.
However when I try compiling it in Code::Blocks I get the following error message:

> ||=== Build: all in Chrono (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
> C:\Chrono\chrono_source\src\chrono\parallel\ChThreadsSync.h||In member function 'void ChSpinlock::Lock()':|
> C:\Chrono\chrono_source\src\chrono\parallel\ChThreadsSync.h|81|error: 'YieldProcessor' was not declared in this scope|
> C:\Chrono\chrono_source\src\chrono\parallel\ChThreadsSync.h|83|error: 'ReadWriteBarrier' was not declared in this scope|
> C:\Chrono\chrono_source\src\chrono\parallel\ChThreadsSync.h||In member function 'void ChSpinlock::Unlock()':|
> C:\Chrono\chrono_source\src\chrono\parallel\ChThreadsSync.h|88|error: 'ReadWriteBarrier' was not declared in this scope|
> src\chrono\CMakeFiles\ChronoEngine.dir\build.make|462|recipe for target 'src/chrono/CMakeFiles/ChronoEngine.dir/physics/ChMarker.cpp.obj' failed|
> CMakeFiles\Makefile2|1040|recipe for target 'src/chrono/CMakeFiles/ChronoEngine.dir/all' failed|
> C:\Chrono\Chrono_CodeBlocks\Makefile|159|recipe for target 'all' failed|
> ||=== Build failed: 6 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 4 second(s)) ===|

The part of the code where the error showing is listed below:

```
#define EBUSY 16
#pragma intrinsic(InterlockedExchange)
#pragma intrinsic(ReadWriteBarrier)

/// Class that wraps a spinlock, a very fast locking mutex
/// that should be used only for short wait periods.
/// This uses MSVC intrinsics to mimic a fast spinlock as
/// in pthreads.h, but without the need of including
/// the pthreads library for windows.
/// See http://locklessinc.com/articles/pthreads_on_windows/
class ChApi ChSpinlock {
  public:
ChSpinlock() { lock = 0; }
~ChSpinlock() {}
void Lock() {
    while (InterlockedExchange(&lock, EBUSY)) {
        /* Don't lock the bus whilst waiting */
        while (lock) {
            YieldProcessor();
            /* Compiler barrier.  Prevent caching of *l */
            ReadWriteBarrier();
        }
    }
}
void Unlock() {
    ReadWriteBarrier();
    lock = 0;
}

  private:
typedef long pseudo_pthread_spinlock_t;
pseudo_pthread_spinlock_t lock;
};
```

So it is some code to make it run on VisualStudio as I understand.
My question is, how can I make this compile with MinGW compiler?

Comment: This is `C++` not `C`. `C` does not have classes, so please tag your questions properly.

Comment: You cannot use any Microsoft-only Visual Studio/VC++ features that do not appear in the gcc compiler on Linux.   You have to stick to ANSI C++.

Comment: Those are all workarounds to avoid using `pthreads.h`. On Linux you would probably **want** to use pthreads.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Is there any method for getting around this issue or is this code simply 'locked' to the Visual Studio compiler? Mayby by including `pthreads.h` in the code?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like a library problem, but the code written in that file. YOu need to remove anything that is MSVC specific such as `#pragma intrinsic()`.

See [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gcc.help/5359) for someone working on porting code to GCC.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have tried to remove `#pragma intrinsic()` and some other stuff in my code, but I cant seem to make it work. I think I will try to install a VirtualBox with Ubuntu and try to make the code work there instead...

Comment: I had a look for some good replacements for ReadWriteBarrier compiler intrinsics (Which are deprecated now anyway). You might want to switch to using <atomic> for data which needs synchronised access across threads.